# I am not able to get the data (instances, snapshots, etc.,) with AWS new regon of eu-central-1

Tags: java

I have implemented the Java code like below

```
AmazonEC2Client.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("eu-central-1");
```

I am getting following exception above line of the code

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No region provided.
```

can any one answer about this.

Answer (score 0):

There's something unusual about the way `RegionUtils` initializes itself. Rearranging the code to call `.setRegion()` as late as possible mysteriously fixed the problem for me.